# VBNet - Print message if sentence ended OK

Tags: vb.net

I need to do something like this, but I don't know how to do it in VB.Net.

```
'Start a process. I know how to do this.
Process.start()

'Check if process ended OK and write a message, I don't know how to do this :P
If "process.start()" ended OK
    console.writeline("Process ended OK")
Else
    Console.writeline("Process ended with problems")
End if
```

I would appreciate any help or suggestion. Thanks!!

Comment: `Process.Start("some.exe")` returns a `Process` object. Save the object in a variable, then call `WaitForExit()` on it. Then check its `ExitCode` property - anything other than zero indicates an error.

Comment: Thanks!!! I mixed both answers and everything works perfect :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `HasExited` property to check if the process has completed;

```
' Opening notepad for example
myProcess = Process.Start("Notepad.exe")
```

You can use a timer to wait for 2 sec. for example

```
' Wait 2 seconds.
Thread.Sleep(2000)

' The check
If not myProcess.HasExited Then 
  ...
EndIf
```

Else in case you are testing it on another event or process, you can use `GetProcessesByName()` as below;

```
myProcess = Process.GetProcessesByName("Notepad")
If myProcess.Count > 0 Then
    ' Process is running
Else
    ' Process is not running
End If
```

`Process.GetProcessesByName()` checks if there are any processes that run with a specified name. (no need to include the .exe part)